# Unable to use json response in Django

Tags: django

I am facing a strange issue. I am using Django 1.6. I am getting json response from a view when calling from jquery ajax function. But, the 'data' does not have length property!

```
$.ajax({
         url: request_url,
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data){
         console.log(data);
         console.log(data.length); //gives an error
```

The console.log prints

```
  Object {2: "XX", 5: "YY"}
```

My View

```
def get_items(request, id):

 item_list = Items.objects.filter(cat = id)
 result = {}
 items_dict = {}
 for item in item_list:
     items_dict[item .id] = item.name

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(items_dict),  content_type="application/json")
```

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects don't have .length property in JavaScript. Use the following to get the length:

```
Object.keys(<your-object-here>).length
```